# xAct tensor product

Tags: tensors, xact

I am a beginner of xAct for computation in GR. I am doing component computation in specified charts, and quite often I need to extract the list of components by the function `TableOfComponents`. However, it seems the function cannot recognize tensor product.

Here is my example:

```
In[5]:= g = CTensor[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {-Cart, -Cart}]

Out[5]= CTensor[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {-Cart, -Cart}, 0]

SetCMetric[g, Cart, SignatureOfMetric -> {2, 0, 0}]

In[8]:= TableOfComponents[g[-a, -e] g[e, -b], -{a, Cart}, -{b, Cart}]

Out[8]= {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}

In[10]:= TableOfComponents[
 g[-a, -b] g[-c, -d], -{a, Cart}, -{b, Cart}, -{c, Cart}, -{d, Cart}]

During evaluation of In[10]:= Validate::inhom: Found inhomogeneous indices: {IndexList[], IndexList[-d]}.

During evaluation of In[10]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Null] returned to top level.

Out[10]= Hold[Throw[Null]]
```

I did a bit of search in the manual but can't find a way to make the tensor product work. I don't necessarily need to define a tensor as the tensor product, but at least I need those components. Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.